# Site Guest User should change Language

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, language

i´ve just created a Site in Salesforce. This Site shows my Survey visualforce.
What i want to have is a dropdown on the top right site where the Site guest user can change the language of the survey. But i dont know how to achieve this. Any help or suggestions are aprreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can add to your page a url parameter called lang. Let's say your page is in german and english. your url will look like this: mySite.com/form?lang=de mySite.com/form?lang=en_us

On your visual force page you can add a parameter to your page tage called "language".

eg.

```
<apex:page language="{!$Currentpage.parameters.lang}">
    {!$Label.myTestLabel}
</apex:page>
```